# What could be causing a NullPointerException error when connecting two agents in an AnyLogic model?

Tags: nullpointerexception, agent, connectivity

I have a model with two agents, one of which is a Systems Dynamics model of body temperature, heatGuy, and the other a state chart of an agent moving from A to B, movingGuy.  The heatGuy model needs to know how hard the movingGuy is working, which is captured in the heatGuy variable work. HeatGuy has a dynamic variable exerciseHeat which is defined as myAgent.movingGuy.work
When I try to run the model I get a NullPointerException. for

```
@AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
 public void _assign_exerciseHeat_Formula_xjal() {
  exerciseHeat = 
  myAgent.movingGuy.work 
  ;
  }
```

This same model worked in previous versions of AnyLogic. Anybody have a clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried to do explicit connectTo code on startup to no avail.

Comment: this means that either myAgent, movingGuy or work are null... any of these 3 options are possible, and there's no way to tell with the information you provided.   Check using traceln(myAgent); traceln(myAgent.movingGuy); traceln(myAgent.movingGuy.work ); to see which one it is